# apple push notification limitation

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm wondering if there is a limit to the number of apple push notifications we can send to users at once?

Can I send 100,000 push notifications at once using the APNS service?

Answer (score 17):

If you are sending multiple notifications to the same device within a short period of time, the push service will send only the last one.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG23

Look "Some Notifications Received, but Not All" in that documentation.

Comment: Yes thats true as the last one replaces the ones before.
My case is that i have a big delay in receiving the push notification when sending to a huge number of phones. dunno if i should blame apple or my code.

Comment: If **malinois** is right (i think so), you can make a loop to control the sending of notifications to 20 devices every 3 seconds for example

Comment: @LuisAscorbe if my device network is turned off for a while, then I just want to know how much notifications APNS Server can hold? If My Server not sending multiple notifications at a time.

Answer (score 11):

[Apple's Tech Note](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2265/_index.html) was recently updated to address this question :

> There are no caps or batch size limits for using APNs. The iOS 6.1
>   press release stated that APNs has sent over 4 trillion push
>   notifications since it was established. It was announced at WWDC 2012
>   that APNs is sending 7 billion notifications daily.
>
> If you're seeing throughput lower than 9,000 notifications per second,
>   your server might benefit from improved error handling logic.

Answer (score 6):

There's no limit on how much notification you can send to Apple APNS server but reminder to avoid using allot of connection because Apple may ban your IP if he think you are doing a DDOS attack.

Also if a user is offline (iPhone out of signal) only the latest push notification will be in saved in apple's APNS server

Comment: Can you please help me with source also if it's true how to hand this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can!
You can also use 20 connections max for the sending of data.

Comment: may I know the reference web page about the max connection limit. thank you

Comment: i think there's a limit... can you please tell me why the need of the 20 connection if one connection can handle all the push? is it just to speed up the sending? or anything else?
Thank you

Comment: @LolaRun if your service has more than 1 running instance(behind load banacer for example) each instance can hold 1 connection