# Push notification connection open close daily limit for IOS

Tags: apple-push-notifications

I couldn't find any push notification document saying we can make `xx` number of requests per day.
I execute a cron which runs every 5 minutes, and on run it will open a connection, send the notification and disconnect.

Will this create any issues, 5 minutes cron a day means 288 request (or connection open and close). Will apple consider this as Denial of Service attack.

Please advise.

Comment: possible duplicate of [apple push notification limitation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421252/apple-push-notification-limitation)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we need to send 500 notifications at a time then it is not a good practice to open a connection, send notification and then close connection. Instead we can open a connection, put a loop for sending 500 notifications and then disconnect it when all are complete.