# Push notification fails at 600th message

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I'm sending `iOS Push Notifications` in the `Enhanced Notification Format` using PHP.

When I send the same message to the same device >= 600 times in a single connection, it sometimes fails at the 600th time with a status code 8 error (Invalid Token). The token is obviously valid since I'm receiving the notifications on a real device.

This happens on both the sandbox and production server.

What could be the cause of this? Is there a rate limit?

Answer (score 0):

provided link possibly answers your issue.
it depicts there are max connections limit at once and DDOS behavior is also assessed possibly.

[apple push notification limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421252/apple-push-notification-limitation)